# Why is my ActionDrawer showing behind my Content?

Tags: android

Title pretty much says it all.  When on a tablet and in landscape mode the ActionDrawer is suppose to stay open and that is what is shown below.

Here is the xml for layout-sw720dp-land

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <com.mobile.library.custom.ActionDrawerListView
          android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/tableBackground"
          android:layout_gravity="start" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawer_content_margin" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the normal layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawer_content_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.mobile.library.custom.ActionDrawerListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/tableBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like I circled some of the images from the ActionDrawer
[image]

Comment: drawer layout should be last in resorce file

Comment: **"...in landscape mode the ActionDrawer is suppose to stay open..."** : Just to clarify...fixed permanently and the user can't close it in anyway? If that's the case you're using the wrong approach and should be looking at a master-detail landscape layout (I'm assuming your `content_frame` is used with a `Fragment` or `Fragments`).

Comment: @Squonk that makes sense, I will look into that for next sprint.

Comment: I was about to accept the answer from Friday but it seems to be gone.  Anyhow, changing the order was the solution along with doing a clean build on Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in a while but I believe you have to change the order:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.mobile.library.custom.ActionDrawerListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/tableBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>
         <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/drawer_content_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```